# What does this regular expression in joomla mean?

Tags: regex, joomla

I was trying to install joomla on my website. While installing joomla, I was asked to create a MYSQl user. But I couldn't because, everytime I type as password, it gives a message saying the paswword doesn't meet the reqular expression requirement. Given below is the regular expression

```
'(?=^.{8,}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$'
```

What does this mean? What password can I give? Give an example of a password that will pass this regular expression test. Please help me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> (?=^.{8,}$)

This part means has 8 more more characters, and the match starts at the start of input.

> ((?=.*\d)

Means contains a digit.

> |(?=.*\W+))

Or contains something that is neither a letter or a digit

> (?![.\n])

not starting with a dot or UNIX newline.

> (?=.*[A-Z])

Contains at least one capital letter.

> (?=.*[a-z])

Contains at least one lowercase letter

> .*$

Consists entirely of non-newline characters and the matched group will contain the entire string.

Comment: I was writing the same thing! +1 for my answer ;)

Comment: I never would have given the split explanations. Awesome :)

Comment: @George Kalyan, Yes, I believe so.  The proof is in the pudding though.

Answer (score 1):

Password should be 8 symbols or more, atleast one digit or a non-character , atleast one lower alpha and atleast one upper alpha and not beginning with `.` or newline ( seriously?)

Example: Manojlds9