# password regex for PHP with 3 possible conditions

Tags: php, regex, passwords

Is it even possible to write a regex for PHP with the following conditions - in a one line regex?

The password must contain any *ONE* of the following:

1. Contain a letter and a digit.
2. Contain a letter and a special character
3. Contain a digit and a special character.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800156/what-does-this-regular-expression-in-joomla-mean/

Comment: What is a *special character*?

Comment: @alex: !@#$%^&*()-_=+[]{};':",./<>?\|`~ :)

Comment: Hm, reading that, am I getting warm with this: `(?=.*[a-zA-Z\d]) | (?=.*[a-zA-Z\W]) | (?=.*[\d\W]).*$`

Comment: yes @mingos. which I assume is \W.  I want to even allow stuff like ¥.

Answer (score 0):

This one must contain: One number, one uppercase and one lowercase letter:

```
^\w*(?=\w*\d)(?=\w*[a-z])(?=\w*[A-Z])\w*$
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex I came up with is very close:

`(?=.*[a-zA-Z\d])(?=.*[a-zA-Z\W])(?=.*[\d\W]).*$`

It succeeds in requiring any of the 3 combinations:

1. Must contain a letter and a digit.
       OR
2. Must contain a letter and a special character
       OR
3. Must contain a digit and a special character.

The only problem left is that whitespace can be substituted for any part of the above combos, and the password will work.  I want whitespace to be allowed, but for one of the 3 requirements to still be met for the password to pass, whitespace or not.

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas as to how to complete this regex?

Comment: and sorry, I don't want to allow whitespace, just spaces.